# What happens when I edit item.csv

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There's this file called `item.csv` in the `dumps` folder. I opens it and it's basically a table with all these information of blocks and items. So, I see a column saying "`HasBlock`". I scroll down and realize that `TRUE` means you can place that item and `FALSE` means you can't place that item.

[image: Content of <code>item.csv</code> when opened using Microsoft Excel:mac 2011]

So I'm asking, if I change a non-placeable item "`stick`" to placable (change `FALSE` to `TRUE`), then what will happen? Will there be any crashes, data loss, stuffs?_

Comment: It'll either crash, or you'll get the "missing texture" block when you place it

Comment: Why don't you answer it...? Just asking.

Comment: Because that's not really considered an answer by Arquade standards...

Comment: Why not try it yourself, on a new creative world?

Comment: @SaintWacko Because when I change `item.csv`, all my saves will be affected and I don't know if it will change my save and stuffs. Yeah. (TBH I am not good at computer.)

Comment: You could back up all your saves and try it, if you're really curious. The worst thing that could happen in this case is you'd have to reinstall Minecraft, but that's not likely. You should be able to change it back when you're done testing, I would guess.

Comment: I doubt changing it would actually affect anything. Two reasons: Firstly, the way Minecraft works internally blocks and items are different, and secondly, it's a file in the `dumps` folder, which is usually a folder for crashes, data logging, and other information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nothing will happen

I tried this on Minecraft Mac, I changed stick to `TRUE`, and I could not place it in the game, nor did there seem to be any glitches.

This could be either due to the fact that items work differently from blocks, or it could be due to the fact that this is a *reporting* file, not a configuration file, as @hedgehog1029 pointed out in the comments.